# Помогите составить SELECT запрос mysql. Yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2, eav

Здравствуйте!
У меня есть таблица, в ней хранятся данные по династическим полям. Выглядит она так:

```
id | product_id | category_id | field_id | value_string | value_int
1  | 15         | 120         | 1        | Бренд-1      | 0
1  | 16         | 120         | 1        | Бренд-2      | 0
1  | 15         | 120         | 2        | null         | 5
1  | 16         | 120         | 2        | null         | 15
1  | 17         | 120         | 1        | Бренд-1      | 0
1  | 17         | 120         | 2        | null         | 55
```

field_id с id 1 - поле бренда, с id 2 - размер

Мне нужно получить product_id у которых поле бренд (field_id - 1) равен "Бренд-1" и "Бренд-2" и поле размер (field_id - 2) с диапазоном к примеру от 5 до 40

Из данных выше, результатом должен быть product_id с 15 и 16. product_id с 17 не подходит по диапазону, хоть и поле бренд содержит "Бренд-1 "

Подскажите в какую сторону идти. Хотелось бы пример реализации на Yii2, но буду благодарен и за чистый sql пример.

P.S.

Возможно я не так построил таблицу с данными, если да, то подскажите что не так и как лучше.

Спасибо! Всем добра!

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день.
На YII2 этот запрос может выглядеть так

```
Model_name::find()
            ->select('product_id')->distinct()
            ->where('in', 'product_id', ['Бренд-1','Бренд-2'])
            ->orWhere(['between', 'product_id', 'Бренд-1','Бренд-2'])
            ->all();
```

Детально ознакомиться можно [здесь](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-query-builder.md#%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-).

Answer (score -1):

Вариант 1

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM `table`
WHERE (field_id = 1 AND value_string IN ('Бренд-1','Бренд-2'))
   OR (field_id = 2 AND value_int BETWEEN 5 AND 40)
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT field_id) = 2
```

Вариант 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.product_id 
FROM `table` t1, `table` t2
WHERE (t1.field_id = 1 AND t1.value_string IN ('Бренд-1','Бренд-2'))
  AND (t2.field_id = 2 AND t2.value_int BETWEEN 5 AND 40)
  AND t1.product_id = t2.product_id
```

Ну и вообще - уж если взяли модель EAV, так почитайте про неё побольше...

PS. Как это превратить в Yii2-код - я фиг знает.

Comment: Увеличить количество `COUNT(DISTINCT field_id)` для варианта 1. Вариант 2 для потребует соответствующего увеличения количества копий таблицы и потому малопригоден. PS. А про EAV и типовые операции на ней всё же почитайте... тогда и спрашивать, может, не понадобится.